# With Spring Security OAuth2, how do I limit a client to only allow certain user types

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

**Scenario**
We are using Spring Security 2 with OAuth2 integration in our system.
In the system there is different user types and different internal and external OAuth clients. 
Some of these clients only want User type A to be allowed to log in while others only want to allow type B.

**Question**
I've been looking at different places to inject this logic and the only place I can see where one would get both username and client id is in the ApprovalStore interface which means I could potentially implement an ApprovalStore that return empty Approvals for the undesired combinations.

Is this the correct place or is there a better place to put this logic?